# Cohomology of the dual Abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, cohomology, abelian-varieties

I am interested in the (degree $1$) Betti cohomology of the dual $A^\vee$ of an Abelian variety $A$ (say, over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$). We can even assume $A$ to be an elliptic curve, if this makes things easier.

I think that there should be a canonical (natural?) identification $H^1(A^\vee) \cong H^1(A)^\vee$, but I do not know how this works. In particular, there should be a **minus sign** hiding somewhere: a polarization, which is in particular a symmetric isogeny $A \to A^\vee$, induces an **anti**-symmetric linear map $H^1(A) \to H^1(A)^\vee$. How does this happen, if $H^1(-)$ is a functor which respects duality (is it?).

**Remark:** I think that there should also be some cohomological twists somewhere, but I do not think that they affect the sign?

I must have read about this stuff somewhere, but I cannot find it anymore, so I would be happy if anybody could point me to a (reasonably down-to-earth) reference.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=V/\Lambda$ be a complex torus. The dual complex torus $X^{\vee}$ is
defined to be $\bar{V}/\Lambda^{\prime}$, where $\bar{V}$ is the space of
$\mathbb{C}$-antilinear forms $l\colon V\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and
$$
\Lambda^{\prime}=\{l\in\bar{V}\mid l(\Lambda)\subset\mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
Now $\Lambda^{\prime}$ is dual to $\mathbb{Z}$ by the obvious pairing, so
$H_{1}(X,\mathbb{Z)}$ and $H_{1}(X^{\vee},\mathbb{Z}{})$ are dual (almost by
definition). To transfer this to cohomology, use Poincar'{e} duality.

The Appell--Humbert theorem shows that $X^{\vee}$ is canonically isomorphic to
$\mathrm{Pic}^{0}(X)$ (so is the dual abelian variety if $X$ is an abelian variety).

See Birkenhake-Lange, Complex Abelian Varieties, 2.4.

For the map $H_{1}(A,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_{1}(A^{\vee},\mathbb{Z}{})$
defined by a polarization of $A,$ see Mumford, Abelian Varieties, Section 24
(here the two obvious pairings on $H_{1}(A,\mathbb{Z}{})$ do differ by a minus
sign).

Comment: This goes in the right direction, but I think that the main issue is still not addressed. Namely, changing the sign of the map $H_1(A,\mathbb{Z}) \to H_1(A^\vee,\mathbb{Z})$ does not change its parity ($f$ is symmetric iff $-f$ is symmetric). My question is rather: given that $f:A \to A^\vee$ is symmetric (i.e., $f^\vee: A \cong A^{\vee\vee} \to A^\vee$ is equal to $f$), why is the induced map $H^1(f):H^1(A) \to H^1(A^\vee)$ anti-symmetric? This has to do with the way in which we identify $H^1(A^\vee) \cong H^1(A)^\vee$ (through the Weil pairing), but the details are not yet clear to me.